# Haskell Win32 equivalents for CreateMutex and COPYDATASTRUCT in a "single instance app"?

Tags: winapi, haskell

I currently have a resource light "unmanaged" Windows C++ application using:

- `CreateMutex` to ensure there is at most a single instance of the application.
- `COPYDATASTRUCT` to pass command line parameters over to that single instance, should another instance attempt to start (after sending data, it will then quit).

The use case is a simple one: launch a new application instance to open a file specified on the command line, or otherwise open the file in a previously-launched application instance.

How could I achieve the same behaviour in a Haskell program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `CreateMutex` isn't offered in the [`Win32` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32) that comes with GHC. You'll need to either bind to it yourself using the [FFI](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1490008) or emulate it in a cross-platform way. One trick commonly used on Linux is to choose a particular filename to act as the "mutex"; if it doesn't exist, you create it and write down how to contact you then delete it when you exit, while if it does, you read the contact information out of it to find out how to connect to the already running process. This approach does have downsides: if either your app or the computer as a whole goes down, you'll have stale contact information.

For IPC, I think there's a number of cross-platform interfaces. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) has an excellent list; especially suitable for doing this task in Haskell are [sockets](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network), [(named) pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-Files.html#v%3acreateNamedPipe), and [dbus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus). For the latter two, you may need Cygwin, since they ultimately depend on getting the unix package installed.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I think I'll focus on the FFI approach for this particular project.  
  

I see the FFI Cook Book has some info on structs in FFI, and hopefully the void* in the COPYDATASTRUCT is handled similarly to the c string example they show:  
    http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_cook_book#Working_with_structs